# Node.js crypto PBKDF2 function returns different values on v8 vs v10

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, hash, salt

This node code snippet returns different values based on the node platform version.  I have two identical instances (except for the node version) in EC2 running Ubuntu 14.04.

```
"use strict";
var crypto = require("crypto");
crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 1000, 32, function(err, derivedKey) {
if (err) {
console.error(err);
} else {
console.log(new Buffer(derivedKey).toString('base64'));
}
});
```

On node **v0.8.28** the console value is:

bsKIwr7Ci8KtfsKuwp3CnhDCqgYSJANPw61Iw5A/w4vCrcKWwotWAGfChFPCnVIU

On node **v0.10.5** the value is:

boi+i61+rp2eEKoGEiQDT+1I0D/LrZaLVgBnhFOdUhQ=

This is a huge problem since we are upgrading the node version on the app and passwords cannot be decrypted properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's strange how you find answers after you ask for help.

By passing the encoding type to the Buffer function like this:

```
console.log(new Buffer(derivedKey,'binary').toString('base64'));
```

...I can get the same hash.

[image: console snippets]

It turns out the default type was changed from binary to utf8, so 'binary' needs to be specified now.
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback (see bottom notes)